# Problema com sessão CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Quando eu faço a autenticação do usuário na minha aplicação, eu salvo algumas informações desse usuário em sessões. Isso feito no Controller *Usuario*, só que quando vou recuperar esses dados em outro Controller, eles não existem. Sendo que fiz um teste, imprimi todos os dados da sessão no meu Controller *Usuario*, e eles apareceram, mas em outro Controller, esses dados não aparecem.

Comment: Está usando sessão do CodeIgniter o nativa do php?

Comment: não, estou utilizando do CodeIgniter

Comment: Na outra controller você fez load da lib? Recomendo colocar no autoloader.

Comment: Exato Luis, eu carrego a lib session no arquivo autoloader

Comment: Está ativado os cookies de seu navegador? (Parece uma pergunta besta, mas as vezes é as coisas mínimas que falham). Da uma olhada no manual pra ver se te ajuda em algo. http://www.plasmadesign.com.br/codeigniter/user_guide-pt_BR/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Também verifiquei isso Luis, mas ainda sem sucesso...

Comment: Por acaso esta usando banco de dados? Qual versão do CI esta usando? E como esta criando esses dados na session? Tem como colocar um código para quem sabe facilitar?